# SQL to JSON output getting cutoff at the end

Tags: sql, json, powershell, t-sql

I am trying to convert my sql query into a JSON format I have used FOR JSON PATH at the end and also FOR JSON AUTO but my results are getting cut off at the end. I cant show the output message but I can show my code with variables replaced. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what SQL engine are you using? SQL server? Oracle etc..? and are you trying to write the results to a file?

Comment: SQL server  i believe and I am trying to write the results to a file

Comment: when you are running your query outside the powershell script does it run as expected?

Comment: the query runs fine just the formatting to json is the problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the powershell feature of ConvertTo-JSON was more effective than the for JSON path command in SQL . I recommend using ConvertTo-Json if using sql and powershell i found my answer here 
http://mac-blog.org.ua/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-convertto-json/

Answer (score 0):

try using `-MaxCharLength`

So something like this

```
If (!(Get-Module -Name sqlps))
    {
        Push-Location
        #Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking
        Pop-Location
    }

    If (!$userName) {
        $SQLResponce = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQL_SERVER -MaxCharLength <some large enough number> -InputFile $SCRIPTPATH -Database 'webserver' -querytimeout 0
    }
    Else {
        $SQLResponce = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQL_SERVER -MaxCharLength <some large enough number> -U $userName -P $password -InputFile $SCRIPTPATH -Database 'webserver' -querytimeout 0
        }

    $SQLResponce #Save this out to a file once you get it to be json in the responce
```

Comment: :( still the same result at the very end of the line it shows .... and doesnt display the end of the json like this [{ (some data) .... and never ends the JSON formatting. however if i take out the json formatting the query returns with the whole data set

Comment: what is the value you are using for -MaxCharLength <some large enough number>, you should use 4000 which is max

Comment: still the same result with 4000

Comment: i believe the issue may be from escaping strings

Comment: trying this now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-escapes-special-characters-and-control-characters-sql-server

Comment: it appears that after a certain length the output becomes ... no matter what type is returned

Comment: do you have to use powershell or you can use other technologies

Comment: I have to use powershell as is boss's request

Comment: how about writing directly to a file rather than into a variable then to a file? using the following param Out-File -filePath <yourfilepath>